# Calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{3\sin(x)-3x \cos(x)}{x^3}\right)^\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, infinitesimals

This is an exercise from today's exam and I think I did something wrong:

Calculate the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{3\sin(x)-3x\cos(x)}{x^3}\right)^{1/x}.$$

To tackle this problem I used equivalent infinitesimals: $1-\cos(x) \sim \frac{x^2}{2}$ as $(x\to 0)$ and $\sin(x)\sim x$ as $(x\to 0)$.

Then our limit:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{3\sin(x)-3x\cos(x)}{x^3}\right)^{1/x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{3x-3x\cos(x)}{x^3}\right)^{1/x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{3x(1-\cos(x))}{x^3}\right)^{1/x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{3x \frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}\right)^{1/x} \\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{1/x}
\end{align}$$

Now I split the limit to see what the effect of negative $x$ will be:

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{1/x}=+\infty$

$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{1/x}=0$

I graphed the function and the limit seems to be 1 from both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3\sin{x}-3x\cos{x}=3\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-...\right)-3x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-...\right)=$$
$$=x^3-\frac{1}{10}x^5+...,$$
which says that your limit is equal to $1$.

Comment: I didnt really want the answer, I wanted to know where is my procedure flawed

Comment: @user605734 MBS You made mistake, when calculated the coefficient before $x^3$. You need to take more addend in the Taylor  series for $\sin$.

Comment: Is the method of changing sin(x) and 1-cos(x) with their respective equivalent infinitesimals valid in this limit?

Comment: Yes, of course, it's works. But you need to take the right approximation.

Comment: Well I understand your answer but still I haven't found where my mistake lies

Comment: @user605734 MBS It's not enough to write $\sin{x}\sim x$. You need $\sin{x}\sim x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}.$ This is your mistake.

Comment: No need to go to degree $5$.

Comment: @egreg What happens if it's degree $4$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It's an odd function, isn't it? The base is $1+o(x)$.

Comment: @egreg Which says that you saw it and we need to go after third degree.